# Try Catch, AddHandler to log exceptions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to create a Sub that Handles the Try-Catch Exception Thrown Event.

I need to add each exception message to a single log file, without having to 
add LogEx(ex) (my sub for adding a string in a log file) in every single Try-Catch block, that's where the need for this event handler came up.

I've searched about it a lot, but i only found ways to create event handlers triggered by unhandled exceptions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is currently happens in every Try-Catch block?

Comment: Can you post your code? What have you tried?

Comment: There is a global place to handle exceptions globally.  If you are going to ever make a decision in some piece of code to handle an exception you have to know if the exception is going to bubble up (throw) and get handled globally or stop right there (catch) in which case you'll need to log it.

Comment: In theory if you are using your own exception objects then they could log themselves at some point in their life cycle but I'm not sure that would be considered good practice.

Comment: Here's the story:
We built a webpage - application for a client,
we tested it for months, it worked perfectly,
but since the last 2 updates, they get errors we don't,
so the only way to test them, was by keeping error logs on their server, since in our environment it still runs great.
We can send them an update, with logging added in every try block, but the code is huge,that's why i wanted to add an event to do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, .NET does not raise application level events for handled exceptions, as they are simply control-flow.

Considering this, you will have to edit all of your error handling one way or the other, either adding the method as you suggest, or by bubbling your errors using `throw();` and ultimately considering all errors at the global level using the `application_error` event. I recommend this approach because it is more maintainable should you want to change your logging method or add additional logic here.

Comment: Thanks, i would appreciate it if you could brief me more about the application_error event. I'm currently searching on Google.

Comment: Since their is no way of creating an event for handled exceptions,i guess i have to append each try-catch block and add my log method.
But i believe its still good to have an event for logging unhandled exceptions, even though every risky part of our code is wrapped in try-catch blocks :P